# Clojure macro that doesn't need space next to it

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp

Trying to create a macro form of Haskell's lambda syntax, I'm pretty close except one last tweak, the / (which should be a \, but can't grumble..) needs a space next to it, is there any way to make it so my macro doesn't need space between it and it's first argument?

for instance:

`(reduce (/x y -> x y) [1 2 3])`

instead of:

`(reduce (/ x y -> x y) [1 2 3])`

I suspect this isn't possible, but only way to know for sure is to ask people who know, so what's the word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Macros cannot change the lexical syntax of the language.  That requires read-macros, which Clojure doesn't have.

Comment: To clarify slightly, Clojure does have reader macros (`'`, `#(...)` are examples) but, unlike other Lisps, it doesn't let you make your own.

Answer (score 2):

No, but if you wanted to do something more ambitious, you could define another macro `with-haskell-lambdas` that you wrap your entire namespace in. That macro could look through all the forms under it, eg with tree-seq, find symbols of the form `/x`, and replace them with `/ x` instead.

Comment: Can this be done? The answerer before you eludes to it being something clojure doesn't support..

Comment: Having a macro echo its body as its expansion with certain tweaks applied (such as symbols of a certain form being replaced by other values) is totally doable and does not involve any changes to the surface syntax of the language. As it happens though, `/foo` is not a valid symbol in Clojure, so this still won't work. On the other hand, you could try and do it with the actual λ character. If you prohibit all other use of it, this would actually be fairly straightforward (with manageable complications around metadata and such).

Comment: NB. prohibiting other uses of the λ character (at least as the first character in the name of a symbol) is important, as if you're not willing to do that, you'd have to be able to determine whether a given symbol starting with it should be replaced or not, which is impossible in full generality with an open set of special constructs (macros).

Comment: Forgot to add that a macro must return a single form, but in Clojure top-level `do` forms are processed as if their bodies were spliced into flow of code at that point, so at top level a macro really can effectively echo its body (or rather the body of call to it, meaning its argument expressions; this is accomplished by returning `(do ~@body)`; you can use something like `(do ~@(transform body))` or `(let [new-body (transform body)] \`(do ~@new-body))` to apply transformations).

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Yes, it is possible.  My answer presumes that you want a local transformation.  If you're fine with using a code-walking macro form wrapping your code, you can do it.